# как стилизоват результаты поиска

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Я сделаль живой поиск на сайте но не понимаю как стилизовать чтобы результат поиска показался по столбцу
есть фото
примерно вот так

1. результат поиска
2. результат поиска
3. результат поиска

```css
.layout {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

.layout TD {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}

.col11 {
  text-align: center;
  /* ТОВАР НОМИ */
  background: #fc0;
  /* Цвет фона первой колонки */
  width: 70px;
  /* Ширина первой колонки */
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col2 {
  background: #afccdb;
  /* Цвет фона второй колонки */
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  /* Ширина первой колонки */
  min-width: 54px;
}

.col3 {
  background: #fc0;
  /* Цвет фона третьей колонки */
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  /* Ширина первой колонки */
  min-width: 59px;
}

.col4 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #afccdb;
  /* Цвет фона второй колонки */
  width: 155px;
  /* Ширина первой колонки */
  min-width: 155px;
}

.col5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 750px;
  background: #fc0;
  /* Цвет фона третьей колонки */
  width: 155px;
  /* Ширина первой колонки */
  min-width: 155px;
}

.col6 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #afccdb;
  /* Цвет фона второй колонки */
}
```

```html
<!-- ЖИВОЙ ПОИСК -->
<!-- QIDIRUV -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- СКРИПТ ЖИВОЙ ПОИСК -->
  <!-- QIDIRUV -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#search").keypress(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'search.php',
          data: {
            name: $("#search").val(),
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $(".col11").html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <!-- СКРИПТ ЖИВОЙ ПОИСК -->
  <!-- QIDIRUV -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#search").keypress(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'searc.php',
          data: {
            name: $("#search").val(),
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <table class="layout" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="col11"> </td>
      <td class="col2">СОНИ</td>
      <td class="col3">НАРХИ</td>
      <td class="col4">ЯРОКЛИК МУДДАТИ</td>
      <td class="col5">СЕРИЯСИ</td>
      <td class="col6">ННН</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[image: фото с сайта]

`

```
PHP`
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE  Name  LIKE '%".$_POST['name']."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "  <tr>
                  <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
                </tr>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "<tr>  <td>0 result's found   </td>  </tr>";
}

?>`
```

Comment: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); ...` - ?

Comment: и не должно было. Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: `<tr>
            <td>Sobirov Ulug'bek</td>

          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Sarvar Sirojov</td>

          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Xoshim</td>

          </tr>
kas.php:86  <tr>
            <td>Sarvar Sirojov</td>

          </tr>
kas.php:86  <tr>
            <td>Sobirov Ulug'bek</td>

          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Sarvar Sirojov</td>

          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Xoshim</td>

          </tr>`

Comment: Почему у вас два похожих скрипта для поиска?

Comment: @Сарвар Данные должны приходить не в виде уже сформированной html страницы, на сервере измените тип отправляемых данных в виде обьекта или массива данных. Свойства и стили уже присвоите у клиента(JS).

Comment: @Сарвар Поправьте ваш вопрос и все что Вы написали в комментарии добавьте в правках.

Comment: https://u.to/17U6Gw Возврат данных в JSON формате